# Mathematica 11.3 on Windows 10 crash on startup

Tags: windows, crash

hoping someone may be able to provide some help with resolving this issue, I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out what's causing the crash. Only started happening this morning.
I launch the application, it's does its loading and initializing this and that, then bam .. both blank screens and not responding, just an application hang with no errors. as seen in the screenshot below.

I've uninstalled and fully removed all traces of the application including registry entries, even tried rolling back to 11.1 but have had 0 luck :( 
When I installed 11.1 it loaded up the messages window but a huge loopy spam error was appearing, some internal self test error .. I didn't get a chance to screenshot it unfortunately. Hoping someone might have some sort of solution or fix I can try. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Sounds like something that the support is supposed to handle...

Comment: I'm in the wrong place aren't I? haha oops.

Comment: I am fighting with the support concerning this subject without any success. I have got a problem (which was not as bad as the one described here) when I installed MMA 11.3 on Win7 with simultaneous uninstalling the previous 11.2 version. By multiple trials, I have found that installing both 11.2 and  then11.3 helps to remove at least, the most severe problems. Try this. Maybe it can help. My personal impression that there is a very serious problem in the new version.

Comment: @Elias No it is a right place. You just received a tip to simultaneously address the Technical Support here:  http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?source=nav. There you can find a mail where to write a letter with the support request.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch In a way it's good to know I'm not the only one. I have tried doing the update from previous version to 11.3 but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Thanks for the tip both of you. I will flick support a message as well  see how we go.

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks again for the responses. Support got back to me with the following response which resolved my issue. Hopefully others may find this helpful ..

Comment: We assume you're using Windows and have successfully installed at least one Mathematica version on this particular computer before? 

Many program problems can be resolved by resetting Mathematica's configuration. Can you please try removing or renaming all these folders:

• C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Wolfram
• C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Mathematica
• C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Wolfram
• C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica
• C:\ProgramData\Mathematica

http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464

Comment: @Elias Could be an issue with the default printer. See my comment at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180427/mathematica-11-3-keeps-crashing-on-initializing-kernel